# Address prefixes

Tags: wallets, account, address

Maybe anybody know address prefixes for tezos? Like this for bitcoin https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this file https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml

The relevant section is the `Prefix` module at the end

```
module Prefix = struct

  (* 32 *)
  let block_hash = "\001\052" (* B(51) *)
  let operation_hash = "\005\116" (* o(51) *)
  let operation_list_hash = "\133\233" (* Lo(52) *)
  let operation_list_list_hash = "\029\159\109" (* LLo(53) *)
  let protocol_hash = "\002\170" (* P(51) *)
  let context_hash = "\079\199" (* Co(52) *)

  (* 20 *)
  let ed25519_public_key_hash = "\006\161\159" (* tz1(36) *)
  let secp256k1_public_key_hash = "\006\161\161" (* tz2(36) *)
  let p256_public_key_hash = "\006\161\164" (* tz3(36) *)

  (* 16 *)
  let cryptobox_public_key_hash = "\153\103" (* id(30) *)

  (* 32 *)
  let ed25519_seed = "\013\015\058\007" (* edsk(54) *)
  let ed25519_public_key = "\013\015\037\217" (* edpk(54) *)
  let secp256k1_secret_key = "\017\162\224\201" (* spsk(54) *)
  let p256_secret_key = "\016\081\238\189" (* p2sk(54) *)

  (* 56 *)
  let ed25519_encrypted_seed = "\007\090\060\179\041" (* edesk(88) *)
  let secp256k1_encrypted_secret_key = "\009\237\241\174\150" (* spesk(88) *)
  let p256_encrypted_secret_key = "\009\048\057\115\171" (* p2esk(88) *)

  (* 33 *)
  let secp256k1_public_key = "\003\254\226\086" (* sppk(55) *)
  let p256_public_key = "\003\178\139\127" (* p2pk(55) *)
  let secp256k1_scalar = "\038\248\136" (* SSp(53) *)
  let secp256k1_element = "\005\092\000" (* GSp(54) *)

  (* 64 *)
  let ed25519_secret_key = "\043\246\078\007" (* edsk(98) *)
  let ed25519_signature = "\009\245\205\134\018" (* edsig(99) *)
  let secp256k1_signature =  "\013\115\101\019\063" (* spsig1(99) *)
  let p256_signature =  "\054\240\044\052" (* p2sig(98) *)
  let generic_signature = "\004\130\043" (* sig(96) *)

  (* 4 *)
  let chain_id = "\087\082\000" (* Net(15) *)

end
```

Comment: I already seen this file. I takes from it BIP32 private and public keys. But where can I get addresses and wif?

Comment: There's no standard WIF format for Tezos. Public key hashes are all defined in there.